# How to mock database in testing

Tags: database, go, mocking

I am writing tests and was able to simulate a database for sql query using go-sqlmock. But how can I test handlers, that is, the headers I can’t imagine. Here is an example:

```
func (env *EnvironmentUser) GetUserHandler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(params["id"])
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    user, err := env.Db.GetUser(int(id))
    if err != nil {
        if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        }
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(user)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

GetUser - listing:

```
row := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1", id)
    err = row.Scan(&user.Id, &user.Email, &user.Login, &user.Fullname,
        &user.Password, &user.AccVerified)
    if err != nil {
        return models.User{}, err
    }
    return user, nil
```

How do I check the correctness of all haders??

Comment: Take a look at the net/httptest package. You can create a test server, and test your handlers in unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should be **how to call a handler and record the response**, as per the examples in [httptest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest), you can do something like below using [testify](http://github.com/stretchr/testify)

```
req, err := http.NewRequest(...)
rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
env.GetUserHandler(rec, req)
require.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, rec.Code)
require.Equal(t, "...", rec.Header().Get("..."))
```

**EDIT**

If you prefer to use only the stdlib, the last two lines become

```
if http.StatusOK != rec.Code {
  t.Errorf(...)
}
if "..." != rec.Header().Get("...") {
  t.Errorf(...)
}
```

Comment: No external testing library is necessary. The stdlib `testing` and `httptest` packages are sufficient to do what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Adrian sure, you don't have to use a testing library. But I like using this one, and that's why I mentioned it in my answer. Feel free to post your solution